Number of 4 digit numbers that are divisible by 4 and are made up from digits smaller than 6
I'm learning combinatorics by myself, and I don't understand what's wrong with my solution.
There are 5 possibilities for the 1st digit and 6 possibilities for the 2nd, meaning 30 combinations: 10,11,12,...,20,21,22,... and so on. Since the last 2 digits need to be divisible by 4, I concluded that there are 14 options (00,04,08,12,...,52). Why can't I just multiply the 30 possible combinations with 14 possibilities for the last 2 digits resulting in 5 times 6 times 14 = 420 combinations?

Try starting with the last two digits and then look at the leading digit. Otherwise you risk double-counting solutions.

I don't understand why I would be double counting though (I probably am, because the solution in the book is smaller). The first 2 digits are 10,11,12,...,20,21,22,...,50.51,...,55 and there are 30 of them. I add 14 different options of the last 2 digits (00,04,08,...,52) to each of the 30 possibilities, resulting in 30*14 different numbers, right?

I only see $9$ options for the last two digits:  ${00,04,12,20,24,32,40,44,52}$  Your short list incorrectly allows $08$ for example.

Oh man, I forgot about the constraint in this part... Silly me. Thank you very much

As mentioned in the comments, the set of last two digits is $\{00,04,12,20,24,32,40,44,52\}$, and not what you mentioned. That will give you the correct answer.
Hope this helps. :)
